# blogger - filtering archive list widget by labels

Tags: archive, blogger, label

I have made a blogger site for a friend. She wanted 2 blogs on the one site which I managed to achieve using search and labels.

http://thewishingtreeandotherdreams.blogspot.co.nz/search/label/moon

http://thewishingtreeandotherdreams.blogspot.co.nz/search/label/blog

Now what I want to do is also filter the archive widget based on the above labels.

I know I will have to have a second archive widget so one shows only "moon" labeled posts and the other only shows "blog" labeled posts

My programming knowledge however is VERY limited. Has anyone else already done this. Do you have code you could share with me?

Answer (score 0):

[Here's a script](https://github.com/jhwilson/Create-a-Blogger-archive-page) with similar functionality but not include nesting by dates. Only copy and edit the next code into new HTML/JavaScript widget.

```
<script src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/jhwilson/Create-a-Blogger-archive-page/Make-Blogger-Archive-Page.js"></script>
<script src="http://NAME_OF_YOUR_BLOG.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default/-/LABEL_NAME?max-results=500&amp;alt=json-in-script&amp;callback=LoadTheArchive"></script>
```

If adds some CSS could be look better.